# Initialize object properties using itself constructor

Tags: javascript

I have a function in costructor to load some data. Can I use constructor to initialize itself on success load?

```js
function User(userId, fullName = '', email = '') {
  this.userId = iserId;
  this.fullName = fullName;
  this.fullName = email;

  this.loadUser = function(url) {
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        userId: this.userId
      },
      success: function(data) {
        this(this.userId, data.user.fullName, data.user.email); //???????????????
      },
    });
  }
}

let user = new User(123);
user.loadUser('myUrl');
```

Comment: No, but you can extract those initialization statements to a method, and call it from both the constructor and the `loadUser()` method...

Comment: No, this doesn't work. See [Is it bad practice to have a constructor function return a Promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24398699/1048572). Write a *static* method `User.load` that returns a promise for a new instance.

Comment: @Bergi My constructor doesn't return promise. It's AJAX function, that can be called after instantiating of object.

Comment: @MikhailKulikov `$.ajax` does return a promise, even if `loadUser` doesn't yet `return` that (it should). But regardless, you want to do an asynchronous call in your constructor to initialise the instance (whether with promises or plain callbacks), and that is what you should not do. No good reason to instantiate an empty object and later load data - do it the other way round: load the data first, then use it to instantiate a complete object.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, you right about $.ajax and asynchronous call. In real app I use pubsub callbacks to handle it. The question is not about it.

Comment: Doesn't matter. Same advice for *any* asynchronous initialisation.